# how can i optimize this method

Tags: c#

is there a better way to optimize this piece of code?? I am checking if each item in the collection has property classID , then do my logic. Any better way where I do an enumerate only for documents having the property

```
if( source != null && source.Count > 0 )
            {
                foreach( var item in source )
                {
                    string customerName = string.Empty;
                    var jsonContent = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( item.ToString() );
                    if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( (string)jsonContent["ClassId"] ) )
                    {....my logic....
```

Comment: Do you need other data than `ClassId` from each `item`?

Comment: yes i need a check on classID but later on i need 2 more item from the document. i am actually moving the document from one place to another and i need to move one with classId in it

Comment: With [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) you define a query like this: `from data in source let item = JObject.Parse(data) where !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)item["ClassId"]) select data;`. Then you can call the `foreach` on this.

Comment: if you are sure , can you please frame it properly as an answer, i should do foreach for which collection here? data?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the filtering logic like this via [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm):

```
var filteredData = from data in source
                   let item = JObject.Parse(data)
                   where !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)item["ClassId"])
                   select data;
```

Then you can iterate through the filtered data with a simple `foreach` loop

```
foreach (var record in filteredData)
{
   //your logic
}
```

---

I've assumed that your `source` is a `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: also can you tell me if I do this way will it work (from data in source
                 let trigger = data.GetPropertyValue<bool?>( "ClassId" )
                 where !trigger.HasValue || trigger == true)

Comment: source is  IReadOnlyList<Document>

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint Yes it might work. You can simplify `|| trigger == true` to `|| trigger`